# ArrayAdapter<String> Duplicates Items with Activity onCreate

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter<String>` Constructor inside of my Activitys `onCreate`. My problem is that each time the `onCreate` method of the Activity that contains the `ArrayAdapter` Constructer is called, the `ArrayAdapter` appends items to the items in the previous `onCreate` call, thus the same items are duplicated every time the `onCreate` method is called.

An example would be:
1st call to Activity - ArrayAdapter = blue, black, brown
2nd call to Activity - ArrayAdapter = blue, black, brown, blue, black, brown
3rd call to Activity - ArrayAdapter = blue, black, brown, blue, black, brown, blue, black, brown

My Constructor looks like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.adapter,colors);
```

Basically, I need the ArrayAdapter to remain constant on multiple calls to the Activity's `onCreate`.

Comment: Can you post your code where you fill out `colors`?

Comment: If you're doing that in the Activity's constructor, then you need to put it in onCreate() or call List#clear().  The system won't necessarily create a now Activity object reference.

Comment: My ArrayAdapter Constructor is inside the Activity onCreate(). If the Activity is destroyed and onCreate is called again. The ArrayAdapter list of items is duplicated.

Comment: As you said, your `Activity` is destroyed, then clear `colors` at the `onDestroy()`. That will solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since items are getting appended to the list each time `Activity` is created, 
    so before adding the elements to the list follow one of these conditions.

First way

```
onCreate(){ 
        if(colors.size()==0){
    // add the elements there};
    }
```

And the Second way..

```
onCreate() {
  colors.clear();
//add the elements here.
```

Option 1 is preferred if you are adding the same items each and every time.

Option 2 is preferred if you are adding different items every time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this would be to include the ArrayAdapter setup and initialization to within the onCreate() method of the activity. This way, each time the activity is called, the ArrayAdapter is initialized as a new object and there won't be any previous values to hold on to.